# jwt.exceptions.DecodeError: Invalid crypto padding

Tags: python, authentication, jwt

i am trying to decode a simple jwt this one

```
eyJraWQiOiJlWGF1bm1MIiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2FwcGxlaWQuYXBwbGUuY29tIiwiYXVkIjoiY29tLm1kbC5lbnRlcmN5IiwiZXhwIjoxNjI3MzgyMTI3LCJpYXQiOjE2MjcyOTU3MjcsInN1YiI6IjAwMTUxMC5hNjQ0MzcyOWE3OTU0ZmQyYTE2NjcyN2NjODY0ZDUyZi4wODI4IiwiY19oYXNoIjoiVl9yUG1Db1Vab0lmejlJQW9WcEFNZyIsImVtYWlsIjoiZnJlZGVyaWNrLm1kbEBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJlbWFpbF92ZXJpZmllZCI6InRydWUiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE2MjcyOTU3MjcsIm5vbmNlX3N1cHBvcnRlZCI6dHJ1ZX0.DDc3G6jJbsLXYX_F3GQ851mEukVDAMvySDPWwWfsmQOmi8w_ItCUaMwSMp0djzzFy3dLpF2cMp67n
```

i manage to decode it in success in the following link here you can check it https://jwt.io/

but when i am trying with python i have no success.Here is my code

```
import jwt



def main(args):
  

      encoded_jwt = "eyJraWQiOiJlWGF1bm1MIiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2FwcGxlaWQuYXBwbGUuY29tIiwiYXVkIjoiY29tLm1kbC5lbnRlcmN5IiwiZXhwIjoxNjI3MzgyMTI3LCJpYXQiOjE2MjcyOTU3MjcsInN1YiI6IjAwMTUxMC5hNjQ0MzcyOWE3OTU0ZmQyYTE2NjcyN2NjODY0ZDUyZi4wODI4IiwiY19oYXNoIjoiVl9yUG1Db1Vab0lmejlJQW9WcEFNZyIsImVtYWlsIjoiZnJlZGVyaWNrLm1kbEBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJlbWFpbF92ZXJpZmllZCI6InRydWUiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE2MjcyOTU3MjcsIm5vbmNlX3N1cHBvcnRlZCI6dHJ1ZX0.DDc3G6jJbsLXYX_F3GQ851mEukVDAMvySDPWwWfsmQOmi8w_ItCUaMwSMp0djzzFy3dLpF2cMp67n"
        val=jwt.decode(encoded_jwt, options={"verify_signature": False})
        print(val)
        return;
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main(0)
```

Here is the error that i got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\jwt\venv\lib\site-packages\jwt\api_jws.py", line 211, in _load
    signature = base64url_decode(crypto_segment)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\jwt\venv\lib\site-packages\jwt\utils.py", line 33, in base64url_decode
    return base64.urlsafe_b64decode(input)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\base64.py", line 133, in urlsafe_b64decode
    return b64decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\base64.py", line 87, in b64decode
    return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
binascii.Error: Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (77) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\jwt\jwts.py", line 13, in <module>
    main(3)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\jwt\jwts.py", line 8, in main
    val=jwt.decode(encoded_jwt, options={"verify_signature": False})
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\jwt\venv\lib\site-packages\jwt\api_jwt.py", line 119, in decode
    decoded = self.decode_complete(jwt, key, algorithms, options, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\jwt\venv\lib\site-packages\jwt\api_jwt.py", line 90, in decode_complete
    decoded = api_jws.decode_complete(
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\jwt\venv\lib\site-packages\jwt\api_jws.py", line 146, in decode_complete
    payload, signing_input, header, signature = self._load(jwt)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\jwt\venv\lib\site-packages\jwt\api_jws.py", line 213, in _load
    raise DecodeError("Invalid crypto padding") from err
jwt.exceptions.DecodeError: Invalid crypto padding
```

Answer (score -1):

when you encode your decoded token https://jwt.io/ website first time you token started with (" ") this you seen two warning,because of ("") this.
after this, not use("")then warning are not show again.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.